# Adding noise to matrix elements with a specific value

Tags: r, noise

This is a very specific question; so I just tell you what I am dealing with:

I have a giant matrix with 2 columns - column 1 refers to time, column 2 to a molecule concentration.
The molecule signal is artificial thats why the baseline is flat (picture). In reality it should be slightly noisy[image]

Therefore, I would like to add noise out of a normal distribution;
I have actually quantified the elements that have this baseline value:

```
numb=length(App[,2][App[,2]==min(App[,2])])
noise=rnorm(numb)
```

I am struggling now with the addition of this random noise to the elements

```
App[,2]==min(App[,2])
```

I tried an if-loop:

```
if(App[,2]==min(App[,2])) {

    App[,2]=App[,2]=+noise
  }
```

but for some reason it does not work. (Error "In if (App[, 1] == min(App[, 1])) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used)

Do you have a tip for me?

Best wishes and many thanks!

Comment: Maybe that? `App[ App[,2] == min(App[,2])] ,2] = App[ App[,2] == min(App[,2])] ,2] +noise`

Comment: If it's necessary, here's an explanation of the error. `App[, 1]` is a vector of length `> 1` (say `n`), `min(App[, 1])` is a vector of length `1`. When comparing the two vectors with `==`, what's returned (call it `ret`) is a vector of length `n`. As `if` doesn't know what to do with this vector, it takes the first element so if  `App[1, 1] == min(App[, 1]` is `true`, the `if` condition is satisfied and vice versa. You could, however, use `ret` to index `App` and proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that could help :

```
baseline.index = which(App[,2] == min(App[,2]))
noise = rnorm( length (  baseline.index ))
App[baseline.index,2] = App[baseline.index,2] + noise
```

Comment: thank you very much - this works out fine :) - sadly, it does not really look realistic though, but I am one step closer

Comment: @Arne The whole point is to choose which points you want to change. In this case you stored the indicies of those in the `baseline.index` . Line 2 is generating noise, just as you did. Just instead of using the condition, I used the indecies of the base line. And finally, I am asking R to add the noise to the rows that have the baseline only. If this isn't clear yet, try to `print (baseline.index)` , `print(App[baseline.index,])`

Comment: yes, I am aware of that :) only the noise does not match a realistic calcium baseline curve because it switches way to fast. But that is an issue for itself. Your code is lovely :).